# Java File does not exists but File.getAbsoluteFile() exists

Tags: java, java-7

Does anyone encountered the case when a `java.io.File` doesn't exist but the calling `getAbsoluteFile()` method on the file instance returns a file that does exist. And why this happen?

[image]

Note

1. I am on Linux plus Oracle Java runtime with version `1.7.0_95-b00`
2. I've passed in a JVM option `-Duser.dir=/path/to/somewhere` when
       launching the tomcat instance

Comment: Does this happen in the debugger watches only? What if you call these methods in your `try` block and print the results?

Comment: It happens in both program and the debugger watches

Comment: Does this happen in tomcat only or can you reproduce the same with a simple standalone application ([mcve])?

Comment: At the moment I reproduce it in a tomcat process. I will check if I can verify it with a minimal example when I got some time. For now I have to [workaround that](https://github.com/greenlaw110/java-tool/commit/f36e7f0ee09d4e01c3e7515c2c5ea7ae624a59f7) to catch up the project schedule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably not mess around with `user.dir`. Rather, change to that directory *before* launching the Tomcat.

`File.getAbsoluteFile()` is assuming that `user.dir` is the directory you are really in, but you aren’t.

Based on your observation, I think `File.exists()` is mapped directly to `stat` on the operating system level. And `File.getAbsoluteFile()` is just `new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), getPath())`.

Under the assumption that `user.dir` is the operating system’s current working directory, these two implementations are correct and reasonable. But in your case, they differ, and this (assumed) implementation can explain what you are experiencing.

Comment: Does that mean there are some internal state in `java.io.File` that might not be synchronized with `System`'s `user.dir` property?

Comment: fair enough. File.exists in the end relies on the return result of `public native int getBooleanAttributes0(File f);` which is an native call.