# FileInputStream : No such file or directory

Tags: java

It works well "new FileInputStream(f.getAbsoluteFile())"

```
private byte[] loadFile(String path) throws IOException {
    File f = new File("./build/classes/" + path);
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsoluteFile())) {
        byte[] data = loadFile(is);
        return data;
    }
}
```

And "new FileInputStream(f)"

```
private byte[] loadFile(String path) throws IOException {
    File f = new File("./build/classes/" + path);
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f)) {
        byte[] data = loadFile(is);
        return data;
    }
}
```

throw exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./build/classes/traces/onmethod/ErrorDuration.class (No such file or directory)

at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
```

I can't imagine why.

Comment: because f and f.getAbsoluteFile() are not the same.

Comment: It would be helpful to show the absolute path `f.getAbsoluteFile()`

Comment: Excuse me，where is the difference? @Stultuske

Comment: f.getAbsoluteFile() not getAbsolutePath，return a File object @Erwin Bolwidt

Comment: What do you get when you do `System.out.println(f.getAbsoluteFile().getPath())`?

Comment: Reread my comment, I *said* getAbsoluteFile. Show the value.

Comment: `System.out.println(f.getAbsoluteFile())` shows the absolute path.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt /home/aaa/Github/./build/classes/traces/onmethod/ErrorDuration.class

Comment: @DodgyCodeException  System.out.println(f.getAbsoluteFile().getPath()) :/home/aaa/Github/./build/classes/traces/onmethod/ErrorDurati‌​on.class and
 real path :  /home/aaa/Github/build/classes/traces/onmethod/ErrorDurati‌​on.class

Comment: Do you, at any time, call `System.setProperty("user.dir", ...)`?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I used "-Duser.dir=/home/aaa/Github/" in vm option

Comment: @saav https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880692/java-file-does-not-exists-but-file-getabsolutefile-exists this link I got while reading more about getAbsoluteFile and this will resolve your issue

Comment: What Rohan Kadu says is correct. You shouldn't change user.dir. It doesn't actually change the current working directory of your process; it just changes a system property which is used by `getAbsoluteFile()`. On the other hand, `new FileInputStream(File)` uses the *real* current directory to resolve the file. So instead of `-Duser.dir=`, do `cd /home/aaa/Github` just before you start the application.

Comment: Thanks.It just a uint test，and there's a lot of this ,let me think about how to change it

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you run your two programs from the same working directory.

Also, in the first case, your path is resolved to an **absolute** path first. 
For example: /opt/local/myprod/bin/build/classes/traces/onmethod/ErrorDuration.class

Whle FileInputStream uses the '**simple path**' of your file (File.getPath())

Depending on your current work directory, your permissions and your symbolic links those two paths can mean two different things.

From the directory you run your program - does this path work ?

```
ls ./build/classes/traces/onmethod/ErrorDuration.class
```

Also see: 
[What's the difference between getPath(), getAbsolutePath(), and getCanonicalPath() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath)

Comment: Have you read all the comments? This issue has already been solved.

Comment: so what exactly was the issue ?

Comment: The application was started with `java -Duser.dir=/home/aaa/Github/`. This does not change the current directory of the running Java process, but it affects what `File.getAbsoluteFile()` returns.

Comment: Ah, yes, makes sense, thanks. Didn't see his -user.dir description.